Codecademy Looping Coffee Chatbot Key Exit Words?
I am a beginner student on Codecademy taking the Build Chatbots with Python Skill Path. I am currently on the 13th step (the bonus step) of the Looping Coffee Chatbot project.
"Try finding more ways you can use loops to extend this chatbot! For example:
Add an additional type of drink or an additional option to an existing drink
Allow the chatbot to recognize additional inputs besides 'y' and 'n' – such as 'yes', 'sure', or 'nah' – when it asks the user if they would like another drink
Allow the chatbot to recognize key exit words such as 'stop' or 'bye' that can terminate the order at any step
Feel free to get creative!"
I am trying to allow my chatbot to recognize key exit words such as "stop" or "bye" that can terminate the order at any step. However, I got stuck there, and the Codecademy Forum Post for this project hasn't been opened in 7 months. Here is my code.
script.py:
from utils import print_message, get_size, order_latte
exit_words = ["stop", "bye"]

def coffee_bot():
  print('Welcome to the cafe!')
  order_drink = "y"
  drinks = []
  while order_drink in  ["y", "yes", "affirmative", "amen", "fine", "good", "okay", "true", "yea"]:
    size = get_size()
    if size in exit_words:
      print("Sure, feel free to come back anytime!")
      return
    drink_type = get_drink_type()
    if drink_type in exit_words:
      print("Sure, feel free to come back anytime!")
      return
    drink = '{} {}'.format(size, drink_type)
    print('Alright, that\'s a {}!'.format(drink))
    drinks.append(drink)
    while True:
      order_drink = input("Would you like to order another drink? (y/n) \n> ")
      if order_drink in ["y", "n", "yes", "affirmative", "amen", "fine", "good", "okay", "true", "yea", "nah", "nay", "nix"]:
        break
      elif order_drink in exit_words:
        print("Sure, feel free to come back anytime!")
        return
    print("Okay, so I have:")
    for drink in drinks:
      print("-", drink)
    name = input('Can I get your name please? \n> ')
    if name in exit_words:
      print("Sure, feel free to come back anytime!")
      return
    print('Thanks, {}! Your order will be ready shortly.'.format(name))

def get_drink_type():
  res = input('What type of drink would you like? \n[a] Brewed Coffee \n[b] Mocha \n[c] Latte \n> ')

  if res == 'a':
    return 'brewed coffee'
  elif res == 'b':
    return order_mocha()
  elif res == 'c':
    return order_latte()
  else:
    print_message()
    return get_drink_type()
  
# Define new functions here!
def order_mocha():
  while True:
    res = input("Would you like to try our limited-edition peppermint mocha? \n[a] Sure! \n[b] Maybe next time! \n> ")
    if res == "a":
      return "peppermint mocha"
    elif res == "b":
      return "mocha"
    print_message()

coffee_bot()


utils.py:
exit_words = ["stop", "bye"]
def print_message():
  print('I\'m sorry, I did not understand your selection. Please enter the corresponding letter for your response.')
  
def get_size():
  res = input('What size drink can I get for you? \n[a] Small \n[b] Medium \n[c] Large \n> ')
  
  if res == 'a':
    return 'small'
  elif res == 'b':
    return 'medium'
  elif res == 'c':
    return 'large'
  else:
    print_message()
    return get_size()

def order_latte():
  res = input('And what kind of milk for your latte? \n[a] 2% milk \n[b] Non-fat milk \n[c] Soy milk \n> ')

  if res == 'a':
    return 'latte'
  elif res == 'b':
    return 'non-fat latte'
  elif res == 'c':
    return 'soy latte'
  else:
    print_message()
    return order_latte()


I tried to use an exit word.
I expected it to print "Sure, feel free to come back anytime!" and exit the function.
Instead, it used the print_message function from utils.py.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a specific question - which will come out of your best attempt to understand and locate a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the specific part of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely expect something), and don't understand why.

If you input 'stop' for get_size(), it will hit the else branch, which executes print_message() and then calls get_size() until a valid entry is given. This means that lines like size = get_size() will NEVER evaluate to 'stop' and therefore never trigger the exit condition. This bugged pattern occurs other times in your code.
Probably the easiest patch is to add another elif branch like elif res in exit_words: return res.
